# Ajax function not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, internet-explorer

I have a django form with two fields with choices. The goal is that options in field 2 change based on option selected in field 1.

This is the code:

```
function field1Ajax(args) {
    $.ajax(args).done(function(data) {
        $("select[name='field2'] option").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.val() && $.inArray(parseInt($this.val()), JSON.parse(data)) == -1) {
                $this.hide();
            } else {
                $this.show();
            }
        });
    });
}

(function($) {
    $("select[name='field1']").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("select[name='field2'] option:first").prop('selected', 'selected');
        if($this.val()) {
            var args = { type:"GET", url:"{% url 'app:get_data' %}", data:{'field1': $this.val()} };
            field1Ajax(args);
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

It works well in Chrome or Firefox, but not in IE11.

The warning I see in IE is:

> DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.

I was hoping someone might recognize why this code would fail in IE.

Comment: this problem has already been asked on other site  see https://github.com/krasimir/navigo/issues/68

Comment: Can you please post your answer based on the reference you mention? I looked at it but was unable to figure out a solution.